# How to keep a spreadsheet cell reference fixed when rows are inserted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

Say I have a Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel spreadsheet where the formula in cell A1 is "=SUM($A$5:$A$100)". Assume there is data is cells A5 through A10, but nothing (yet) in A11 through A100.

Now insert a row above A5. This moves the data from the 5th row down and A5 is now blank. Enter something in A5. There is now data in A5 through A11. But the formula in A1 has been updated to "=SUM($A$6:$A$101)" so doesn't include the new cell.

"Absolute reference" markers `$` were used, so I had expected the formula to be fixed.

Is there a way to force the formula in A1 to be constant regardless of whether rows are inserted or deleted lower down?

Ideal would be a general solution that applies to both Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel. If the solutions are unique to each, please note that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hunting, I found a solution that works in both Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets.

Instead of:

```
=SUM($A$5:$A$100)
```

Use:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A5:A"&ROW()+105))
```

This assumes the cell with the formula is A1. Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: This also works :) but fyi INDIRECT is also volatile so use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

One option for your formula in cell A1 is:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,4,0,96))
```

Parameters of OFFSET:

1. Cell reference (think of this as the anchor)
2. Number of rows below cell reference (negative for above)
3. Number of columns to the right of cell reference (negative for left)
4. Height of reference
5. (not used - width of reference)

This works in both Excel and Sheets.

The downside is that OFFSET is volatile, meaning it will be recalculated every time anything on the spreadsheet changes. If you have too many formulae like this, it can slow things down.

Comment: Confirm this works in both Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel ! Think `INDIRECT` is simpler as the formula reference won't need to be looked up when I return to the spreadsheet months later, but `OFFSET` is a neat trick. Another advantage of `INDIRECT` is that if the "anchor" cell is moved, little or no editing will be required. Noted that both are volatile.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This does not work in Google Sheets.

INDIRECT and OFFSET are Volatile functions.  Which means it will recalculate every time there is a change in any cell in any open worksheet.

Instead we can use INDEX which is not volatile:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,5):INDEX(A:A,100))
```

And now since the 5 and 100 are "hard coded" and not tied to a cell it will not change if a new row is inserted.

Comment: Good tip. Shame it doesn't work in Google Sheets. Volatile functions may not be suitable for large spreadsheets. But for small spreadsheets, re-calculating each time a change is made is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A5"):INDIRECT("A100"))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Start the formula at A4 instead of A5, you the loose the feature of data falling off the bottom because the insert will update the bottom row
"A4:A101" after inserting the row.

labels are worth nothing, so if you have a label in A4 it will not upset the sum.

Comment: No. Insert one row, and the formula changes from `A4:A100` to `A5:A101`. Insert another row and it changes again to `A6:A102`.

Comment: And you want that?  why?